# No class found on JApplet using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, classnotfoundexception, netbeans-8, japplet

I am trying to run a simple `JApplet` program with JSP but it says every time:

```
ClassNotFoundException scanner.Scanner
```

Here is the `JApplet` code:

```
package scanner;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit.BeepAction;

public class Scanner extends javax.swing.JApplet {

  private JButton jButton = null;
    @Override
public void init() {

    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 // Construct the button
  setSize(1200, 600);
setLayout(null);

setContentPane(getJButton());
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private JButton getJButton()
  {
    if (this.jButton == null)
    {
      this.jButton = new JButton();
      this.jButton.setBounds(new Rectangle(4, 16, 131, 42));
      this.jButton.setText("Select Device");
      this.jButton.setBackground(Color.white);
      this.jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        //stuff here
    }
  });
}
return this.jButton;
  }

}
```

The JSP file:

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
     </head>
    <body>
    <applet code="scanner.Scanner" archive="Scanner.jar" width="600" height="480"/>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is simple just showing a button. I added the Scanner applet as a jar on my web application. On the web browser it shows `ClassNotFoundException`. Why?
On JSP I used different code, example:

```
code=scanner.Scanner 
code=scanner.Scanner.class
code=scanner.Scanner.java
code=Scanner.class
```

But nothing works

I am using Netbeans.

Comment: What is the structure of the server, showing locations of both the JSP and the Jar file? BTW - See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: BTW 2: Of the four variants shown, only `code=scanner.Scanner` is completely correct, though some of the others might be 'tolerated' by the JVM. But stick to the one that is correct. I suspect the problem here is that the entire Jar is not being found.

Comment: I used this to create the applet. https://www.sitepoint.com/embedding-applet-web-application/

Comment: If that page answers my question, distil the information down to just what I asked, and add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39603967/edit). I have neither the time nor the patience to go through that.